# Android: TableLayout Equal Cols In Code

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to create a TableLayout in code.  Each row in the table should have equally spaced columns.  The content of each cell is the same and is just a square button (I'm trying to create a calendar).

How do I get each column to take up equal width and then take up the full width the table?  Right now the columns are all the same width because they all have the same content, but columns are not expanding to fill the entire width of the table.

The following is what I have tried.  I am extending the TableLayout class which is why I use "this" in the code.  The lines commented out are things I tried that had no effect:

```
this.setStretchAllColumns(true);

TableRow row;
CalendarButton button;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    row = createRow();
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //params.span = 7;
    row.setLayoutParams(params);
    //row.setWeightSum(7);

    for(int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
    {
        button = createCalendarButton();

        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.span = 1;
        row.addView(button, params);
    }

    this.addView(row);
}
```